# How to Obtain Whole JSon file posted along with $.post in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, json

I am posting json data to the asp.net server page along with the $.post method. But Is there any way to obtain whole data and convert it into anon object.

**This is jQuery Code :**

```
var RegisterUser = function() {
    var _username = $("#username");
    var _password = $("#password");
    var _email = $("#email");
    var _firstName = $("#firstName");
    var _lastName = $("#lastName");
    //var _SecurityQuestions = $("#ss");
    var _securityAnswer = $("#securityAnswer");

    //The registration object that will be sent along with the jquery.post method
    var _regObj = {
        username: _username.val(),
        password: _password.val(),
        email: _email.val(),
        firstName: _firstName.val(),
        lastName: _lastName.val(),
        //securityQuestion: _securityQuestions.val(),
        securityAnswer: _securityAnswer.val()
    };

    $.post("login.aspx/callback=RegisterUser",
    _regObj,
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

**C# Code :**

```
public  void RegisterUser() {
   // Here I wanna get the whole json object and convert into like :
   var obj = new JavascriptSerializer().Deserialize(Requetst.PostedJsonObj);
}
```

I couldn't figure out how to solve in that way, I could use Request.Params["email"],etc. but this seems kinda uncool way...

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JSON2.stringify](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js):

```
var RegisterUser = function() {
    var _username = $("#username");
    var _password = $("#password");
    var _email = $("#email");
    var _firstName = $("#firstName");
    var _lastName = $("#lastName");
    //var _SecurityQuestions = $("#ss");
    var _securityAnswer = $("#securityAnswer");

    //The registration object that will be sent along with the jquery.post method
    var _regObj = {
        username: _username.val(),
        password: _password.val(),
        email: _email.val(),
        firstName: _firstName.val(),
        lastName: _lastName.val(),
        //securityQuestion: _securityQuestions.val(),
        securityAnswer: _securityAnswer.val()
    };

    $.post("login.aspx/callback=RegisterUser",
     {data: JSON.stringify(_regObj) },
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

C# Code

```
public  void RegisterUser() {
   // Here I wanna get the whole json object and convert into like :
   var data = Request['data'];
   var obj = new JavascriptSerializer().Deserialize(data);
}
```